# Atribuir método a tipos customizados em Golang

Tags: golang

Possuo um código onde preciso realizar diversos `replaces` e para isso fiz da seguinte maneira:

```
exemplo := "Olá, meu nome é xpto, na verdade xpto da silva xpto"
formated := strings.Replace(exemplo, "xpto", "Fulano")
formated := strings.Replace(formated, "Olá", "oi")

fmt.Println(formated)
```

Para tentar deixar mais "amigável" resolvi criar uma variável do tipo `string` que me permita usar o um método "replace" encadeado, que ficaria da seguinte maneira:

```
exemplo := "Olá, meu nome é xpto, na verdade xpto da silva xpto"
formated := custom(exemplo).replace("xpto", "fulano").replace("olá", "oi")
```

Para isso fiz:

```
type custom string

func (c *custom) replace(old, new string) custom {
    content := string(*c)
    return custom(strings.Replace(content, old, new, -1))
}

func main() {
    text := custom("Olá, nome, Olá, nome")
    fmt.Println(text.replace("Olá", "oi").replace("nome", "nombre"))
```

}

Ao executar o código apenas com 1 `replace` o mesmo é executado com sucesso, porém se eu tentar encadear outro `replace` como no exemplo acima recebo o erro de que não é possível acessar o ponteiro nem o endereço de `text.replace("Olá", "oi")`, acredito que este erro é gerado porque quando retorno o "custom" em `replace` nenhum endereço de memória é atribuído para ele.

> cannot call pointer method on text.replace("Olá", "oi")
>
> cannot take the address of text.replace("Olá", "oi")

Já tentei atribuir o retorno de `replace` para uma variável para gerar um endereço de memória:

```
func (c *custom) replace(old, new string) *custom {
    content := string(*c)
    formated := custom(strings.Replace(content, old, new, -1))

    return &formated
}
```

Só que desta maneira, o `Println` em `main` exibirá o endereço e não o valor.

Como posso usar o valor retornado de uma função em um método encadeado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar um ponteiro, da seguinte maneira:

```
func (c *custom) replace(old, new string) *custom {
    content := string(*c)
    r := custom(strings.Replace(content, old, new, -1))
    return &r
}
```

Então usa-lo como:

```
func main() {
    text := custom("Olá, nome, Olá, nome")
    fmt.Println(*text.replace("Olá", "oi").replace("nome" ,"xx"))
}
```

Isso funcionará como o esperado, use o `*` para recuperar o valor, no `print`.

Uma outra opção é justamente não usar referencias/ponteiros:

```
func (c custom) replace(old, new string) custom {
    return custom(strings.Replace(string(c), old, new, -1))
}

func main() {
    text := custom("Olá, nome, Olá, nome")
    fmt.Println(text.replace("Olá", "oi").replace("nome" ,"xx"))
}
```

Teste isto em https://play.golang.org/p/mrQPxpqDL8s

---

Qual a diferença de um e de outro? Basicamente se você usa `(c *custom)` você está dizendo que a entrada é uma referencia, não o valor.

Logo, se você faz:

```
func (c *custom) replace(old, new string) custom
```

Você espera uma entrada como referencia, mas tem como saída o valor em si. O Golang tenta "converter automaticamente" (ele usa a referencia ao invés do valor em si), veja que isso funciona:

```
text := custom("Olá, nome, Olá, nome")
x := text.replace("Olá", "oi")
y := x.replace("nome", "nombre")

fmt.Println(y)
```

As variáveis são endereçáveis, é possível criar o ponteiro, com `&x`. O problema é que no Golang você não permite criar ponteiros de qualquer coisa, isso é inválido:

```
fmt.Println( (&text.replace("Olá", "oi")).replace("nome", "nombre") )
```

Observe que da o mesmo erro, inclusive se você fizer:

```
fmt.Println( (&text.replace("Olá", "oi")) )
```

Isso é justamente o o Go tenta fazer internamente, e é a causa do "cannot take the address of text.replace("Olá", "oi")".

Segundo a [documentação em "Address Operator"](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators) você só pode criar referencias de variáveis, slices e afins.

Já usando o `c custom` você espera o valor em si, não o ponteiro dele, assim ele funcionará.

Comment: eu achei que só conseguiria acessar um valor se usasse um ponteiro para definir o método `replace` em: `func (c *custom)`; qual a diferença entre usar ou não um ponteiro nesta parte `func (c *custom)`?

Comment: @RFL, editei para acrescentar esse detalhe. Ficaria longo num comentário.

Comment: Só lembrando existem mais diferenças, usando o `c custom` você não pode alterar o valor original, por exemplo [veja aqui](https://play.golang.org/p/UITYYmfUt8n), isso ocorre justamente porque ele não é um ponteiro pro valor original. Mas, me restringir na diferença neste caso especifico, não em todas as diferenças, que inclusive nem sei se sei todas, ahaha.